# Android virtual device on Windows 10: slow to start up, apk not installed but no errors

Tags: android, memory, time, virtual-machine, tablet

I am starting to learn Android programming, currently using Eclipse. I have been using a phone for running apps, but my current assignment requires a tablet.

I have installed a Nexus 7 virtual device on Windows 10 (no HAXM support from Microsoft, yet). Below is the startup code, and my two questions are:

- Is it normal for a virtual device to take 9 minutes from launch to reaching home?
- What would be a basic device you can recommend for learning Fragments?

My thought is that this must be a memory issue, so I am thinking of a tablet+API combination that spares memory and runs Fragments.

```
[2015-03-19 17:55:21 - IntentsLab] ------------------------------
[2015-03-19 17:55:21 - IntentsLab] Android Launch!
[2015-03-19 17:55:21 - IntentsLab] adb is running normally.
[2015-03-19 17:55:21 - IntentsLab] Performing course.labs.intentslab.ActivityLoaderActivity activity launch 
[2015-03-19 17:55:21 - IntentsLab] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Nexus_7_ARMeabi7a'
[2015-03-19 17:55:21 - IntentsLab] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Nexus_7_ARMeabi7a' 
[2015-03-19 17:55:35 - IntentsLab] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2015-03-19 17:55:35 - IntentsLab] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2015-03-19 18:04:24 - IntentsLab] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2015-03-19 18:04:24 - IntentsLab] Uploading IntentsLab.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2015-03-19 18:04:25 - IntentsLab] Installing IntentsLab.apk...
[2015-03-19 18:07:42 - IntentsLab] Failed to install ***.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2015-03-19 18:07:42 - IntentsLab] (null)
[2015-03-19 18:07:43 - IntentsLab] Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if there is no HAXM x86 support yet, then it's completely normal for the ARM emulator to not run, or to take forever to run.

Don't you have real device you can use instead? That would be your best option. Most used Android phones/tablets/GoogleTVs on Ebay or Craigslist should do the trick as long as they're at least Android 3.x.

Also, I think you worry needlessly about the complexity of fragments on different devices. Rearranging fragments for different devices is not the hard part. The hard part is to get fragments running on at least one device, whatever that device may be. So don't worry about testing with a second device, testing on a single device should do for now while you're still learning.